# alluxio not distributing files across the cluster

Tags: apache-spark, alluxio

I'm using 6 node cluster for alluxio(1.4 version),but it does't distributing files across the cluster, one worker only  using 98% and other worker are using  50%-55%
master node using 18% only 
And i'm using "alluxio.user.file.write.location.policy.class=alluxio.client.file.policy.MostAvailableFirstPolicy" in alluxio-site.properties file in all nodes.

Answer (score 0):

`alluxio.user.file.write.location.policy.class` is a client-side property. For it to take effect, it must be on the classpath of the application writing the data to Alluxio. Also note that the policy only applies to newly written files, so existing data will not be actively rebalanced.

[Location policy documentation](https://www.alluxio.org/docs/1.4/en/File-System-API.html#location-policy)